# Use of unresolved identifier 'Model' in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, fmdb

In my Swift project I have created class named Model:

```
class Model : NSObject
{
    func createDatabase(nameOfTheDataBase: String  ) ->String
    {
     // do something and return String
    }
}
```

and when I tried to use this class in another class

```
  public class User
   {
     var databasePath = String()
     var path : String?
     public func create() -> String
    {
     databasePath = Model().createDatabase("ShoppingPad.sqlite")
    // return something
    }
  }
```

This gives an error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Model'

I tried to clean and then build my project. But error reappears.

Comment: First of all please read swift code guidelines, second do you need to inherit from NSObject, second if you dont intend to store the property why not create a class function rather than a instance, FYI your code work for me

Comment: Are the same class compiled within the same target or framework ?

Comment: @sken3r.MI I don't need to inherit my Model class from NSObject. That was just mistake. And my Model class and User class are in different file of same project

Comment: The code works for me as well - but it looks like you're planning to use Model() in a number of places to provide an abstraction layer to your database.  Sounds like you should be using a singleton, otherwise you will be re-creating `Model` each time you use it, and if you extend the functionality to include a context for your database, you will get a different one every time you call it.  At the very least you will be increasing your workload by recreating things that could simply be stored

Comment: @Ressell You are right I am using Model() in another file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do more than just return the database path, you should look into singletons as a means of making the database functions accessible to all classes.  There are lots of tutorials and examples out there, but it looks like this

```
class Model
{
    static let sharedInstance: Model = {
        let instance = Model()
        // setup code
        return instance
    }()

    func createDatabase(nameOfTheDataBase: String  ) ->String
    {
        // do something and return String
        return "Bob"
    }

}

public class User
{
     var databasePath = String()
     var path : String?

    public func create() -> String
    {
        databasePath = sharedModel.createDatabase("ShoppingPad.sqlite")
        // return something
        return databasePath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Model class is inside a different target from User class, Model is not accessible because it's not public.
Try make Model class public and see if it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

This code also works for me. It seems that some error in Xcode .swift file. Take new .swift file & copy paste the whole code in it.

Comment: hello priyanka //